# transform 1D array of list to 2D array

Tags: python, pandas

For example

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.Series(['a b', 'c d'])
t1 = d1.str.split()
a1 = t1.values
```

where a1 would be

```
array([list(['a', 'b']), list(['c', 'd'])], dtype=object)
```

how to transform it to

```
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.stack` on `t1`:

```
In [186]: np.stack(t1)
Out[186]:
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U1')
```

Or `np.array` on `t1.tolist`

```
In [187]: np.array(t1.tolist())
Out[187]:
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U1')
```